# webrtc can not see remote video but can hear audio

Tags: android, webrtc

I am the new in webrtc , I had some problems on webrtc.   i can not see remote video ,but can hear audio below android o .i can see remote video and hear audio on android o.  webrtc version implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003'

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you create well the video track, put it on the stream and also it should be enabled.

Comment: thank you i have resolved it , because of the  coverage problem of surfaceview